# Approximation of roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Consider the polynomial:
$x^7−(3/2)x^6−(43/4)x^5+(115/8)x^4+(135/8)x^3−(61/8)x^2−(81/8)x−(9/4)$

How can I approximate its roots without using Newton's method?

(Using Newton's method I got a root of multiplicity 3)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting a plot you guess and verify zeros at  $x=2,1, -\frac{1}{2}, 3,-3.\;$ The zero at $x=-\frac{1}{2}\;$ has multiplicity $3.\;$ Therefore your polynomial can be written as
$$p(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x+3)\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$$

Comment: But, is there any way to do it without plotting?

Comment: Evaluating at small integers $x$ will give the zeroes $1,2,3,-3.$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the polynomial by $8$. Then you can use the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to reduce the candidates for roots to reduced fractions $p/q$ where $p$ divides $18$ and $q$ divides $8$.